# Replace "n\a" values with missing values in R / tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am looking for an explanation of why this tidy way to replace `"n\a"` with `NA` doesn't work:

```
dta <- tibble(var1 = c("1", "2", "n/a"), var2 = c("n/a", "2", "4"))

> dta %>% mutate(across(everything(), na_if, "n/a"))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  var1  var2 
  <chr> <chr>
1 1     n/a  
2 2     2    
3 n/a   4
```

Comment: Not sure why it doesn't work for you. It does for me! Also, this is obviously a toy dataset, but if you ever find yourself in this situation, I'd recommend: `dta %>% mutate(across(everything(), as.numeric))`. Converting the columns to numeric will automatically put the `NA`'s where you need them.

Comment: Thanks, after updating packages, it now works.

Comment: This is a simpler way: `dta %>% mutate_all(na_if, "n/a")`